# Most suitable programming language for listing all possible bool sequences

Tags: sequence

I need to list all bool sequences of a certain length (say, 100), which satisfy a given set of rules. An example for a rule is: if bit10=bit20=1, then bit35=0.

I wrote a C++ program which enumerates the possible sequences in a few seconds, but it's too long and complicated. Can you recommend me a programming language in which I can achieve this with a significantly shorter code and a (near) similar performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to solve the generalized problem where variable rules are the input to your program, it is called [Satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) or “SAT”. There are several SAT solvers out there, e.g. [CryptoMiniSat](http://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat2/), with different capabilities. You would have to transform your rules into their input format and then run the SAT solver on that.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I will probably stick with sat4j, as it seems to be better documented.